# SVProgressHUD - Showing / Hiding the control quickly causes it to not come up the next time showWithStatus is called

Tags: ios, svprogresshud

I have some source code below which will reproduce this. Calling `showWithStatus` and dismiss before the HUD has a chance to present itself is causing the control to not show the next time `showWithStatus` is called. Does anyone know any workarounds?

```
// Commenting these will show SVProgressHUD
[SVProgressHUD showWithStatus:@"Loading..."];
[SVProgressHUD dismiss];
// Comment above to show SVProgressHUD

[SVProgressHUD showWithStatus:@"Loading..."];
[self performSelector:@selector(dismissHUD) withObject:nil afterDelay:5.0f];
```

EDIT: I have some [source code](https://github.com/tejaswiyvs/SVProgressHUDTest) up here that reproduces this.

Comment: Would be good to file a bug report on the official GitHub project as well. The author possibly knows the answer off the top of his head. Nevertheless, +1 for providing a test case.

Comment: I did .. But there were several open issues there, and thought I might get help quicker here :)

Comment: Sure, nothing wrong with that. Just find it important to notify the maintainer so others (myself included) won't run over the same issues in the future. Glad you did :-) I'll post a comment over there so hopefully it attracts more attention.

Answer (score 0):

I worked around it by doing this for the second HUD display:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(showHud) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];
```

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the problem:

**1. add property**

```
@property (nonatomic, readonly, getter = isDismissing) BOOL dismissing;
```

**2.add flag**

```
- (void)dismissWithDuration:(NSTimeInterval)duration delay:(NSTimeInterval)delay {
    _dismissing = YES;
    ...
        void (^completionBlock)(void) = ^{
            ...
            _dismissing = NO;
        };
    ...
}
```

**Rename function**

```
- (void)showImage:(UIImage)image status:(NSString)status duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
```

**to with name**

```
- (void)showImageSS:(UIImage)image status:(NSString)status duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
```

**3.add delay**

```
- (void)showImage:(UIImage*)image status:(NSString*)status duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    if(self.isDismissing){
        __weak SVProgressHUD *weakSelf = self;
        dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, NSEC_PER_SEC * SVProgressHUDDefaultAnimationDuration),dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [weakSelf showImageSS:image status:status duration:duration];
        });
    }else{
        [self showImageSS:image status:status duration:duration];
    }
}
```

**And**

```
- (void)showImageSS:(UIImage*)image status:(NSString*)status duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    // this is orginal function - (void)showImage:(UIImage)image status:(NSString)status duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration code block
}
```

finsh Thanks Everybody